# C# classes have text file icons in win explorer

Tags: .net, git

My OS is Windows 8.1, I try to clone a c# solution in cmd with:

> git clone projectUrlOnKiln.git

The project is downloaded successfully, and it loads properly, but the C# classes have the text file icon instead of the usual green C# one. I'm completely new to git, do I have a wrong git property somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your file association is set to the wrong application. Microsoft has a full [support article on the topic](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307859).

> To change which program starts when you double-click a file, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Open Windows Explorer by right-clicking the Start button, and then click Explore.
> 2. Click a folder that contains a file of the type that you want Windows to open in a program that you select.
> 3. Right-click the file and, depending on the programs installed on your computer, complete one of the following steps:
>
>    - Click Open With to choose the program that you want.
>    - Point to Open With, and then click Choose Program to choose the program that you want.
> 4. The Open With dialog box is displayed. Use one of the following methods to select the program that you want to use for this file type:
>          * In the Programs list, click the program that you want to use.
>          * Click Browse, locate and then click the program that you want to use, and then click Open.
>          * Click Look for the appropriate program on the Web to browse the Internet for the program that you want to use.
> 5. Click to select the Always use the selected program to open this kind of file check box if it is not selected.
> 6. Click OK.
>
>    Note From now on, Windows XP will open all files that have this file name extension in the program that you selected. To change this, you must follow these steps again and associate a different program with this file name extension.